# Create an editable list in HTML and synchronize it with server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, user-interface, contenteditable

I would like to show a todo list, let the user edit it and synchronize it with the servers.

I am thinking about using a ul tag with the attribute contenteditable.

I generate the original list assigning an attribute at each element which identify it. For example:

```
<ul>
    <li dbid=1>element1</li>
    <li dbid=2>element2</li>
</ul>
```

The user coud modify these elements, delete them and add new ones. I want to track which elements are changed because other attributes (deadline, priority, etc) can be associated with them, so they have an identity, they are not just text.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: the best way to do that is to first try something i mean write some code and if you get stuck somewhere or face a problem in that then ask question concerned with the current problem :)

Comment: start simple by wrapping UL in a form....give inputs name property and work from there. Can listen to `change` on inputs and do server updates within change handlers. On more advanced level can use an object oriented javascript framework....knockout, backbone, angular for example to provide all the listening tools and ajax interface. Take a look here: **http://todomvc.com/**

Comment: What does your server use? PHP? MySQL? Do you have a database?